# How do I set certain colors in an Opengl texture to transparent?

Tags: opengl, transparency, textures

I am trying to create a library i can use to handle 2d rendering in Opengl (c++) i have it all figured out except I can't figure out how to set current colors transparent (ex. being able to set 255, 0, 255 to transparent) I realize from reading on the topic that I need to preprocess the texture and set that color's alpha value to 0 but I have no idea how to do this.

PS: I am using SOIL for loading textures if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I realize from reading on the topic that I need to preprocess the texture and set that color's alpha value to 0 but I have no idea how to do this.

```
for(y = 0; y < image.height; y++) for(x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
    if( image.data[x, y].rgb == colorkey ) {
        image.data[x, y].alpha = 0.0;
    } else {
        image.data[x, y].alpha = 1.0;
    }
}

/* ... */

upload_image_to_texture(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would probably recommend you use alpha transparent textures rather than a color key/chroma key ones unless their is some specific reason not to (ie really low memory or your trying to use the Minecraft ones).

With that said, use shaders. In your fragment shader use the 'discard' keyword when the fragment color matches your color key. There's an [official tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php).